# Looking for a validating bill module

Tags: design, automation, module

My team and I are working on a project which deals with money management. Basically we need a module that could count and verify the authenticity of bundles of bills.

For the moment, we only found finished products for the task but we need to integrate it to the rest of the project.
Is there some module that solves this problem? Does somebody worked with it?

Comment: there is one on almost every vending machine, so, yes, somebody has worked with one

Comment: if you are doing development, then shouldn't you be asking more than yes/no questions?

Comment: I know that vending machines exist, but I did my reserch and I did't found the only part of a vending machine I'm interested in. So it seemed like a good idea to ask here. Maybe somebody has worked in some project like ours. Perhaps the question is not perfect redacted (English is not my first language) but I think if someone has useful information on the topic and interest in helping would understand me anyways and for sure will have more to say than yes/no, like product models, advices, etc. But thanks for the constructive comment!

Comment: google `bill validator` ... it is unclear what you are looking for ... `we only found finished products` does not mean anything specific ... it is unknown what you mean by `finished product` ... by the way, you are the one who asked questions that have a yes/no answer

Answer (score 2):

I worked in the currency validation business for over 15 years. As far as I know nobody makes a module that can handle bundles of bills at one time, that can be built into another product.